# Writing the data of a void pointer to a file

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I am working on some software making use of a encryption library, the underlying mechanics of which I can't change. When the program runs it takes about 10 minuets to generate a public and private key, which is extremely frustrating when trying to debug other parts of the software. I would like to write the keys to a file and read them back to save time.

They keys are void pointers:

`Enc_Key_T secKey = nullptr;`

Where `Enc_Key_T` is defined as `typedef void* Enc_Key_T`

The code I have used to attempt to read and write keys is as follows (only attempted to write the secret key so far):

```
#ifdef WriteKey

    generate_Keys(parameters, &sec_key, &prv_key);

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("sk.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&sec_key, sizeof(Enc_Key_T), sizeof(&sec_key), pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

#else

    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    pFile = fopen("sk.bin", "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        fileError();

    fseek (pFile, 0 , SEEK_END);
    lsize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if(buffer == NULL)
        memError();

    sec_key = (void *) fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);

    fclose(pFile);
    free(buffer);

#endif
```

When I write the file it comes out as 64 byte file, but reading it back in the secret key pointer gets set to a low value memory address, which makes me think I am doing something wrong. I can't find any examples of how this can be done. I'm not even sure it can, as I won't be creating any of the underling structures, so I am just trying to allocate some memory at a location provided by a pointer.

Is there anyway this can be done without having to touch the underlying library that generates the keys?

Comment: At least `sizeof(&sec_key)` this is wrong. It should be `sizeof(sec_key)`.

Comment: You have to understand how the keys are stored. Right now, you're doing the equivalent of trying to copy something knowing only where it is. But how you copy a piece of paper is different from how you copy a sound. You need to know precisely *what* it is to copy it, not just where.

Comment: Please tell me the type of 'Enc_Key_T' is it a class or struct or what? Can you post its declaration if you have it?

sizeof will not be of any help to you unless you show me the declaration of the Enc_Key_T

Comment: @MahmoudFayez He said it's a `void*` in the question.

Comment: [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) doesn't return an address, so obviously that's wrong. The added-cast seems more like something that was added to hide a compiler warning than anything else, which is always a *terrible* idea. I find it hard to imagine an encryption library that doesn't provide a mechanism for serializing key material to a stream, a buffer, *something*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That is what I though might be the problem. The function that actually generates the encryption keys is a load of elliptic curve stuff, so I have no idea 'what' it actually is.

Comment: @MikeS159 That's what you need to know in order to serialize it and deserialize it. You need to understand what data is stored and how. Otherwise, if it happens to work, it's by luck. There's a good chance the data includes pointers to other structures such as the particular curve used. (Are you sure the library doesn't include functions to do this already?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe the data does actually contain pointers to other structures. I will dig around for a function to try and save the key, but my colleague mentioned that this had been a problem for a while, so I don't think it does.

Comment: @MikeS159 It sounds like this library is, bluntly, complete crap. Can it be replaced, fixed, rewritten, or otherwise improved? Do you have the source code?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I do, but it is a collaborative project and we aren't responsible for the library. I will bring it up as something that needs to be added in future.

Comment: @MikeS159 At least write a C++ wrapper... Wait .. this is a real-world application and you wrote your own elliptic curve library? Are you sure that's wise? There's a lot of subtle mistakes you can make if you don't have deep subject matter expertise and there are lots of well-studied libraries available.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's a collaborative project between companies and universities. The library was written by a university involved in it. It is currently only a proof of concept demonstrator. I wouldn't attempt to write anything like that myself. I'm sure there would be plenty more testing and reviews before it was ever used on anything important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: in general, you cannot do that correctly.

Long answer:
The thing that you're missing is the structure, you have no guarantee that Enc_Key_T can be serialized by simply writing memory contents. In addition, even if it just raw random data, there is no known length of it.

In addition, there is no guarantee that the library does not have its own state, bound to the generated keys.

Code issues:

When writing, you have no known length of data. Data that is written is a pointer and then something bogus.

When reading, you don't need a secondary buffer; besides, fread returns number of bytes read, not a pointer to the data. So instead of:

```
buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
if(buffer == NULL)
    memError();

sec_key = (void *) fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
```

you can write:

```
sec_key = (void *) malloc (lSize);
if(sec_key == NULL)
    memError();

if ( 0 == fread(sec_key, 1, lSize, pFile) ) {
  // error
}
```

Comment: Also, he has no idea how many bytes to write. Nor, as you point out, any assurance that he's written anything that makes any sense -- it may just be the address of something that won't exist when he runs the program again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz oh. I missed that writing part was also wrong. There is no known length at all.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are going to debug intensively this application such that you may invest 1 hour building those wrappers I am suggesting.

As you long as you do not know the underlying structure and this library is a black box you have to do the following:

```
void generate_KeysEx(...){
#if DEBUG
     // return dummy keys
#else
    // call this API
#endif
}

void EncryptEx(...){
#if DEBUG
     // return cipher same as plain text
#else
    // call this library API
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From discussions in the comments it doesn't sound like this is possible without capturing the structure in the library, which would require significant code changes.

A very hacky solution I found was to change a few key generation parameters which drastically reduces run time.